# Only last select element gets the option elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-select, appendchild

I am trying to make a code that adds all the item options to each select element. For some reason only the last select element gets the options.
Here is the code:

```
for (var i=0; i<itemcount; i++) {
    var newE=document.createElement("span");
    var newD=document.createElement("input");
    var newS=document.createElement("select");
    newE.id="itemcontainer";
    newD.id="drop"+i;
    newS.id="sel"+i;
    for (var j=0; j<itemos.length; j++) {
        newS.appendChild(itemos[j]);
    }
    newD.type="checkbox";
    newD.name="drop";
    newE.appendChild(newD);
    newE.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Drop? "));
    newE.appendChild(newS);
    container.appendChild(newE);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single `<option>` element can only be in one `<select>` at a time. You're trying to add the same options to many different `<select>` lists, and that can't work.

You have to create new `<option>` elements for each `<select>`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, if you have a large number of these spans, inputs, selects and options to build, you may want to consider caching a base object and .clone()-ing them, as last I checked, that's far faster than performing a new .createElement() each time. Perhaps even faster is a direct .innerHtml() call with a string.

Comment: @mori57 Yeah, I created the options again every time and it worked!!